# Django: collecting users, objects activity stream

Tags: python, django, android-activity

I use django-activity-stream module to collect users activity. 
But when one user (user1) follows another (user2).

I need to fetch activity stream of the following user (user2) and combine all activities sorting by date and time (see code below).

And since activity list grows I think I'll face performance and optimisation issues.
I believe someone already solved similar problems.

Any ideas and advices on how to make activity generation more efficient?

```
def build_activity(raw_activity):
    activity = []
    for item in raw_activity:
        action_object = get_action_object(item)
        activity.append({
            'user': User.objects.get(pk=int(item.actor_object_id)),
            'verb': item.verb,
            'action_object': action_object[1],
            'type': action_object[0],
            'timestamp': timesince(item.timestamp),
            'datetime': item.timestamp,
        })
    return activity


def activity_stream(user):
    from actstream.models import actor_stream
    raw_activity = actor_stream(user)
    activity = build_activity(raw_activity)
    for following in Follow.objects.filter(user=user):
        stream = actor_stream(following.target_user)
        activity += build_activity(stream)
    return sorted(activity, key=lambda item:item['datetime'], reverse=True)
```

Thanks,

Sultan

Comment: " But when one user (user1) follows another (user2)." Then what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over at Fashiolista we've opensourced our approach to building feed systems.
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Feedly
It's currently the largest open source library aimed at solving this problem. Think it also solves your problem of development time vs premature optimization. :)

To start out I would Redis as a datastorage. Later when your site gets larger it often makes sense to move to Cassandra.

The same team which built Feedly also offers a hosted API, which handles the complexity for you. Have a look at [getstream.io](https://getstream.io) At the moment we have client APIs for Python, Ruby, Node and PHP. In addition since its based on a heavily optimized Cassandra setup we can price it far below which a self hosted solution based on Redis would cost you.

In addition have a look at this high scalability post were we explain some of the design decisions involved:
http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/10/28/design-decisions-for-scaling-your-high-traffic-feeds.html

[This tutorial](http://www.mellowmorning.com/2013/10/18/scalable-pinterest-tutorial-feedly-redis/) will help you setup a system like Pinterest's feed using Redis. It's quite easy to get started with.

To learn more about feed design I highly recommend reading some of the articles which we based Feedly on:

- [Yahoo Research Paper](http://research.yahoo.com/files/sigmod278-silberstein.pdf)
- [Twitter 2013 Redis based](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html), with fallback
- [Cassandra at Instagram](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/post/instagram-making-the-switch-to-cassandra-from-redis-75-instasavings)
- [Etsy feed scaling](http://www.slideshare.net/danmckinley/etsy-activity-feeds-architecture/)
- [Facebook history](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Facebook-Software-Stack)
- [Django project](http://justquick.github.com/django-activity-stream/), with good naming conventions. (But database only)
- http://activitystrea.ms/specs/atom/1.0/ (actor, verb, object, target)
- [Quora post on best practises](http://www.quora.com/What-are-best-practices-for-building-something-like-a-News-Feed?q=news%20feeds)
- [Quora scaling a social network feed](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-scaling-issues-to-keep-in-mind-while-developing-a-social-network-feed)
- [Redis ruby example](http://web.archive.org/web/20130525202810/http://blog.waxman.me/how-to-build-a-fast-news-feed-in-redis)
- [FriendFeed approach](http://backchannel.org/blog/friendfeed-schemaless-mysql)
- [Thoonk setup](http://blog.thoonk.com/)
- [Twitter's Approach](http://www.slideshare.net/nkallen/q-con-3770885)

Answer (score 2):

Unless I have a verifiable performance issue, I personally dislike premature optimization as it often has become an endless spiral into insanity for me. You might find this to be the case here as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

But if I were going to optimize this, I might generate another stream, and the timestamps for the actions is set by the action_object timestamp... :)

Comment: Now we went using Redis to store the latest activity stream, really makes it much simple to handle this kind challenges

Comment: @sultan good to know:) I think I will face a similar problem soon. Are you still using django-actstream? Or it's completely rewritten? Thanks!

Comment: no we stopped using it and moved activity into a simple model connected with redis